# What is this hole on the tail of an MD-88?

Tags: aircraft-design, equipment, md-80, dc-9-family

There's a little hole on the leading edge of the vertical stabilizer of this plane:

[image]

What is that? What is its purpose?
Thanks
Source: [Airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Delta-Air-Lines/McDonnell-Douglas-MD-88/1611318/&sid=9df8bdad06e6b8d0858b3d2eaa8e177b)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is the ram air intake for the [air conditioning packs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_cycle_machine).

[image]

Comment: At first I thought it might be the APU intake, but other sites say that the APU intake is near the bottom rear of the fuselage.